# Converting timestamp to MM/DD/YY in sql

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently I have tables that I am trying to join together by dates.

One of them returns a timestamp (2020-12-21 00:13:56.312) and the other 12/21/20. I am trying to make it so I can join these two by date. I am doing this in snowflake and it does not seem that I can use the format() function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake:

TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY')

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`to_timestamp()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html):

```
where mytimestamp = to_timestamp(mystring, 'mm/dd/yy')
```